# Using Excel table, formula that works in all rows, not working on first table row

Tags: excel, automation, formula

I have an Excel table that I'm using to log project events.  I'm using a formula (as seen in the formula bar) to automatically add a time stamp to an entry.  It work on all lines of the table except on the first line.  In the image you can see that the "Date of Entry" cell on line 2 is selected, and that the formula is present, but it's not being activated. I also added an image of the same table with line 3 selected, and you can it contains the same formula.  Iterative calculations is also enabled (see image). So why is the first line of the table (row 2) not firing of the function?

```
 =IF(OR([Event Summary]<>"",[Currently Awaiting]<>""),IF([Date of Entry]=0,NOW(),[Date of Entry]),"")
```

[image]
[image]
[image: Iterat]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enable "iterative calculation" for this to work. Also the formula needs to refer to relative cells like this:

=IF(OR([@[Event summary]]<>"",[@[Currently awaiting]]<>""),IF([@[Date of entry]]="",NOW(),[@[Date of entry]]),"")

Comment: I updated my post to show that iterative calcs is enabled.  I'll also try changing to relative cells, but can you tell me why it's working on all the there rows with out the relative @ prefix??   Every time I make a new row, the formula is added to the cell in the new row and works, just not on the first row??  I"m new to this and fairly confused as to how the @ would operate different than it is.